# Why Rails response takes one minute in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, rest-client

Can't understand why my rails app become make response ultra-slow - in 1 minute!

As i see total time Rails should be: Views 0.2ms +  ActiveRecord 219.5ms + Solr 379.7ms = 599.4ms

But it takes 62615ms, where is it spending the rest of time 62015.6ms?

```
Started POST "/applications/135" for ::1 at 2019-08-05 17:59:04 +0300
Processing by ApplicationController#create as JS

...

Completed 200 OK in 62615ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 219.5ms | Solr: 379.7ms)
```

`config/environments/development.rb`:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.
  # Verifies that versions and hashed value of the package contents in the project's package.json
  config.webpacker.check_yarn_integrity = false

  # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
  # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
  # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations.
  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
  # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
  # number of complex assets.
  config.assets.debug = false

  # Asset digests allow you to set far-future HTTP expiration dates on all assets,
  # yet still be able to expire them through the digest params.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Adds additional error checking when serving assets at runtime.
  # Checks for improperly declared sprockets dependencies.
  # Raises helpful error messages.
  config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  # Raises error for missing translations
  # config.action_view.raise_on_missing_translations = true

  # SMTP configuration
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
    host: ENV['HOST']
  }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :letter_opener
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  # Care if the mailer can't send.
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
end
```

Comment: This seems unusual. Is it happening consistently when you POST to this endpoint?

Comment: yes, currently only on POST!

Comment: I had a similar issue previously, one of old gems caused the issue and slowed my development project. If im not wrong it was one of logging gems...

Comment: It could be compiling assets. Can you post the contents of `config/environments/development.rb` ?

Comment: Also post your gemfile

Comment: Does that happen on any action or only that one? Use a gem like byebug, put a `byebug` breakpoint at the beginning of the action and move through the code to narrow the cause down. Do you use any external API?

Answer (score 0):

Found cause of slow down.
Somebody of our team added delayed service into the controller.

After commenting `#require 'sidekiq/testing/inline'` in the `config/environments/development.rb` and running separate `sidekiq -C config/sidekiq.yml` it solved the problem, now service is running asynchronously.

But problem was inside the service where was the call `RestClient.post(endpoint, payload.to_json, 'api-key': api_key)` which was wrapped into `begin rescue end` block that catch the error (that raises in a minute by RestClient timeout).

```
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 62562ms (ActiveRecord: 191.5ms)

RestClient::Exceptions::ReadTimeout (Timed out reading data from server):
```